# Separate the public/admin area in different asp.net mvc AREA's leads to double controllers?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, asp.net-mvc-areas

My site has multiple public pages showing some lists like news,products etc... everyone can see. So I have a NewsController and ProductController. The Create/Edit action can only be/must only be executed by the admin. When I separate the admin stuff (Create/Edit) from the public stuff(List) I would create 2 areas public/admin each having its own controller. That means I would have TWO ProductController one with List action and one with Create/Edit action and TWO NewsController same game...

Would that make sense? I looks like DRY - don`t repeat yourself!

How would you handle that scenario concerning the new asp.net AREA feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you are repeating yourself? I always create an admin area for crud operations. You should be moving all of your logic outside of your controllers into a separate class, and depending on how big this site, maybe a separate project altogether. Take a look how the Raccoon Blog structures their project. I have learnt a great deal from studying their code. If you are having questions on how to structure your code, I suggest looking over there to - https://github.com/ayende/RaccoonBlog/tree/master/RaccoonBlog.Web. I believe they have an excellent example of how to implement admin areas correctly.

Answer (score 0):

[AuthorizeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx) is how I'd handle it, I wouldn't use Areas to partition permissions.